# nextJS modifying response data from restApi. No idea whats going on

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I am having an issue with the data I am receiving from my express server in my nextjs app.
I am making a fetch request to the endpoint '/product/category/:category'.
If a make this request using postman I get a response like so:

```
"data": [
        {
            "_id": "65a71532c33cc42a6ab218dd",
            "name": "yx1 wireless earphones",
            "description": "description here",
            "new": true,
            "alt": "yx1 wireless earphones",
            "categoryImg": {
                "mobile": "url1",
                "tablet": "url2",
                "desktop": "url3"
            }
        }
    ]
```

This is in my fetchProductsByCategory func:

```
 const res = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:3001/product/category/${category}`
    );

    if (!res.ok) {
      console.log(res);
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
    }

    const data = await res.json();

    return data;
```

The value of 'data' for the exact same endpoint (in fetch function) looks like this:

```
"data": [
        {
            "_id": "65a71532c33cc42a6ab218dd",
            "name": "yx1 wireless earphones",
            "description": "description here",
            "new": true,
            "alt": "yx1 wireless earphones"
        }
    ]
```

the categoryImg property is completely removed? Why is this happening?

I can fix the problem by:

```
import { unstable_noStore as noStore } from "next/cache";
```

And then calling noStore() at the top of the fetchProductsByCategory function. Why does this solve the issue?

I am trying to teach myself web development, this is my first time using nextJS. Sorry if it is a stupid question.

Comment: Hi, Next.js does not change the data received from an endpoint. Could you add more details? Is back-end and front-end Next.js 14? Are you using App router? Filenames?

Answer (score 0):

`import { unstable_noStore as noStore } from "next/cache";` is the hint to understanding the behaviour you're seeing.

In short, Next.js caches `fetch` requests (`GET` & `POST`) and it's down to you to invalidate that cache in some manner. *Note: there are some subtle differences depending on where you're making the fetch requests E.g. route handlers.*

Here's a somewhat contrived example, but hopefully explains the general notion in a succinct way.

Functions for making the requests.

```js
function getCategoryCacheTag(category: string) {
    return `product_category_${category}`;
}

function getCategory(category: string) {
    const url = `http://localhost:3001/product/category/${category}`;

    const request: RequestInit = {
        method: "GET",
        next: {
            // You can do a combination here, don't need both.
            tags: [getCategoryCacheTag(category)], // Apply a tag to the request so we can revalidate the cache on demand
            revalidate: 3600 // Revalidate the cache for this request every 60 minutes
        }
    };

    const response = await fetch(url, request);

    return response;
}

function updateCategory(category: string, someData: any) {
    const url = `http://localhost:3001/product/category/${category}`;

    const request: RequestInit = {
        method: "POST",
        cache: "no-cache" // Never cache this POST request because we're updating the category
        body: JSON.stringify(someData)
    };

    const response = await fetch(url, request);

    return response;
}
```

Update the category and revalidate because we know the category's data should have changed. You'd often call this in a Server Action.

```js
const category = "categoryA";
const response = await updateCategory(category, { dataA: "lorem", dataB: "ipsum"}); // Update the category

if (response.ok) {
    revalidateTag(getCategoryCacheTag(category)); // Revalidate (clear) the category cache using its tag
}
```

It's a bit of a read, but I would highly recommend reading the documentation about Next.js' caching.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#data-cache

Answer (score 0):

Cheers for the replies.
It did have to do with the cache. For some reason I thought the cache would reset each time you start/stop the server in dev mode. Not the case apparently.
What was happening is that I changed the collection (in my db) a while ago so that it included the categoryImg field. nextjs had data cached for these requests from before I changed this field. So when I removed noStore() it was serving cached data. Adding that function forces it to fetch the request each time a user navigated to that page I believe, hence it was grabbing the most recent data?
Any way, I just deleted the .next file, restarted the server and it worked as expected.